# CSS Background Images To Repeat on x left and x Right with out overlapping

Tags: css, background, repeat

Ok so I am trying to set up my background image set up
So its like
<---Repeating image on the left --- Center image --- Repeating image on the right --->

The image on the left is not the same as the image on thie right.

I have tried using this

```
body{
background:
url(../Img/Background-01.png) center top no-repeat,
url(../Img/Background-02.png) right 0 repeat-x,
url(../Img/Background-03.png) left 0 repeat-x;
background-color:#232323;
}
```

But Background-02.png is overlapping Background-03.png resulting in Background-02.png repeating on both the left as well as the right side of the page when its only meant to be repeating on the right.

Here is a screen shot of my design it might give you a beter idear of what i am trying to make
the white boxes are parts of the background layer that are cropt out in there own image to be use on the website [img][http://s7.postimg.org/iy0tm6k2j/Screen_Shot_2014_06_27_at_5_16_13_pm.png[/img]](http://s7.postimg.org/iy0tm6k2j/Screen_Shot_2014_06_27_at_5_16_13_pm.png%5b/img%5d)

any help will be apreeseated to help fix this.
 Ok i worked it out this is what i used

```
'#Container{
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border:thin solid #000;
    z-index:4;
}
#BGCont
    {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:0;
    height:500px;
    }
#BGLeft
    {
    position:absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1;
    background:url(../Img/Background-03.png) left 0 repeat-x;
    height:500px;
    }
#BGRight
    {
    position:absolute;
    width: 50%;
    z-index:2;
    right: 0;
    background:url(../Img/Background-02.png) right 0 repeat-x;
    height:500px;
    }
#BGCenter
    {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 1200px;
    z-index:3;
    background:url(../Img/Background-01.png) center top no-repeat;
    height:500px;
    }'
```

Now my question is is this an ceptable way to do it or is it too messy?

Comment: there is a work-around for this here http://jsfiddle.net/UwZ3V/ , it requires the support for `calc()` function (IE9+), sometimes without using such a useful function, we can't have some elegant solution.

Comment: OK I worked it out THis is what i used

Comment: looks like you've solved it yourself, it's better to add the answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use before and after pseudo classes like below.

```
body
{
 background: url(../Img/Background-01.png) center top no-repeat;
 background-color:#232323;
}
body::before
{
 background:url(../Img/Background-03.png) left 0 repeat-x;
}
body::after
{
 background:url(../Img/Background-02.png) right 0 repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Ok i tryed that but it onley leaves me with background-01.png the other two disapear

Answer (score 0):

By using repeat-x all you're doing is repeating it horizontally, on both left and right side. That's why the second image is overlapping the third one on the right. I suggest editing the image separately and then using it. As by this method you don't specify which side you want to repeat it on, but only the axis, i.e., x or y or horizontal or vertical

or you if you only want to extend it on either sides then you can use this:-
    #leftHalf {
       background: url(../Img/Background-03.png);
       width: 50%;
       position: absolute;
       left: 0px;
       height: 100%;
    }
    #rightHalf {
       background: url(../Img/Background-02.png);
       width: 50%;
       position: absolute;
       right: 0px;
       height: 100%;
    }

Also i had done something similar. I put a gray stop-marker on the left side, a white one on the right, and one of each right where you want the gray to end. In my example i put it at 40%.
    background: #7a7a7a; /* Old browsers */

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #7a7a7a 0%, #a5a5a5 40%, #ffffff 40%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7a7a7a), color-stop(40%,#a5a5a5), color-stop(40%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #7a7a7a 0%,#a5a5a5 40%,#ffffff 40%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #7a7a7a 0%,#a5a5a5 40%,#ffffff 40%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */

background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #7a7a7a 0%,#a5a5a5 40%,#ffffff 40%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */

background: linear-gradient(top,  #7a7a7a 0%,#a5a5a5 40%,#ffffff 40%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7a7a7a', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: see if these help..    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212028/background-repeat-only-on-one-side-of-the-site-layout-content-centered

Comment: if you want it in a gradient form then this might help:- http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ or    http://i3.minus.com/i8yJaMpBaRGow.jpg

Comment: Ok yeah i worked out what was causing the ovvlapign but i can not work out how to fix it. but What do u mean by edit the image separately? they are seprit images

Comment: I mean put them together using photoshop and other such programs, adobe or picassa or paint, whichever one youre comfortable with

Comment: I've edited my answer to give 3 possible solutions, check whichever one suits you best. I also just found something online. Check this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/byYKE/

Comment: Yeah i had desigend it in illastrator and i used it to cut it up in the first place

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want 3 images to show,

<---Repeating image on the left --- Center image --- Repeating image on the right --->

There are tow ways to set that,
1- Create divs and assign images to these divs

<--- left Div --- Center Div--- right Div --->

2- Create Tables and make 23 column

<--- C1--- C2--- C3 --->

Comment: If i did it that way then ill just get a giant scroll bar. the purpous of the repeating images is just to have something fulling the space on the sides of the webpage that's out side of the centered container. If I used a div or a table wouldn't it just make the page wider as well? and create an annoying horizontal scrollbar?